# Python turtle passing a tuple to turtle.shapesize() method gives error 'TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float''

Tags: python, typeerror, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

pos = (100,100)
size = (30, 30)         # This is the tuple
screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

turtle.goto(pos)         # This statement works fine
turtle.shapesize(size)   # This line gives error


screen.exitonclick()
```

The abovementioned code gives me the error `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` as I try to pass tuple as input to turtle.shapesize() method but tuple works fine with turtle.goto() method without any error.
Also when I use "*size" instead of just "size" as in `turtle.goto(*size)` in the same line, the code runs without error. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The ability of the `goto` method to accept two separate coordinates or a `tuple` of those two coordinates is not a general feature of Python, nor turtle, but rather coded explicitly in the `goto` method:

```
if y is None:  # one argument
    self._goto(Vec2D(*x))  # unpack container and make a Vec2D
else:  # two arguments
    self._goto(Vec2D(x, y))  # pass them along as a Vec2D
```

Whereas `shapesize()` has three distinct arguments and hasn't been coded to accept a `tuple` with those three values.  However, it has been extensively coded to successfully deal with any and/or several of those argument being left off the call:

```
if stretch_wid is stretch_len is outline is None:
    ...
if stretch_wid == 0 or stretch_len == 0:
    ...  # error
if stretch_wid is not None:
    if stretch_len is None:
        ...
elif stretch_len is not None:
    ...
if outline is None:
    ...
```

These are API design choices made by the programmer and documented as part of the methods.

> when I use "*size" instead of just "size" as in turtle.goto(*size) in
> the same line, the code runs without error. Why?

You're simply unpacking the container the same way that `goto` would do if you had passed the container instead.